# SQL query query about selecting particular number of rows

Tags: sql, mysql

For example -
`SELECT * FROM user_names` returns about 100 rows.
How would you query to get only row no.30 to row no.40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with MySQL you would do it as follows:

SELECT * FROM user_names LIMIT 30,10

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number`

```
with CTE_Table 
as (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) AS Row_Number 

FROM  dbo.a)
 select * from CTE_Table

WHERE Row_Number BETWEEN 30 AND 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY user_names.id) as RowNumber, *
from user_names) un
where un.RowNumber between 30 and 40

replace the ORDER BY clause with whatever you want to order by.